# Separating first paragraph from others

Tags: php, html

Let's say, that I have the following source output:

```
<p>This is first paragraph</p>
<p>This is second paragraph</p>
<p>This is third paragraph</p>
```

What I want to achieve is... I want to split them, first paragraph goes into one variable, others into other. Like:

```
$first = "<p>This is first paragraph</p>";
$next = "<p>This is second paragraph</p><p>This is third paragraph</p>";
```

Because those are generated by TinyMCE and user input, I can never know when user will add `<br />` or other tags, which will cause TinyMCE to generate a new code-break `\r\n`. Therefore, all the solutions which split them by looking for `\r\n` won't work this time.

**Any advice?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = str_replace('</P>', '</p>', $input); # In case of upper case tags
list($first, $next) = explode('</p>', $input, 2);
$first .= '</p>';
```

Comment: +1 Nice and easy. inb4 "Use a DOM parser" etc. You *could* consider to replace the first two lines with `preg_split('#</p>#i', $input, 2)` to avoid mutating `$input`. (Other, unrelated `</P>` tags *may* be affected by `str_replace()`.)

Comment: Thanks, this will do it for now!